# Solana genesis accounts

Tags: solana, solana-cli

What is purpose of these accounts to be hard coded in the code. What If I want to run my own local instance of solana validator, will these accounts affect any part of my local instance.

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Can you provide more information about specific genesis accounts that you're worried about? Some of them are very important.  For example, the mint holding all SOL in the network is part of genesis.  Also, stake accounts are part of genesis, which are necessary for smooth operation of the staking logic.  Either way, a local validator with `solana-test-validator` only starts with the absolute minimum: a validator identity, vote account, stake account, and a SOL mint.

Comment: Actually I want to run completely new solana chain and there are number of accounts in [gensis_accounts.rs](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/genesis/src/genesis_accounts.rs) file. and I want to know about these accounts that is this necessary to keep these accounts as it for running new chain.

Comment: These accounts are not particularly useful, especially since you very likely don't have the keys to them!  Your best bet is to go through the Solana tokenomics and then decide which of these are useful before including them.  And if you do, be sure to update the keys to those controlled by you or other partners so that huge amounts of tokens aren't untouchable!

Comment: What is I want to start my own custom cluster, could you please give me some guidance for that, how I can spin up my own cluster ?

Comment: what is --entrypoint in solana-validator and Why I can't use it in local environement